# Emails are not getting sent from SalesForce Sandbox . Have already configured Deliverability to 'All Mails'

Tags: salesforce1-app

Emails are not getting sent from SalesForce Sandbox. Have already configured Deliverability to 'All Mails'. Checked email logs and found below details.

```
   Mail Event – P - Permanent Failure  
   Delivery Stage - reading BANNER  
   554 SFDCSMTPin.xxxxxx.com - 554 Error code (The transaction failed)
```

**Any idea what can be the reason behind it.**

Comment: did you try to send email to different email with another domain (gmail for example)? 554 is commonly used by dns blacklists when shooing away blacklisted servers

Comment: Thanks for your response. I tried with Gmail and outlook domain, i am getting email change notifications but not getting any email from Case object's workflow and approval process. The issue is same "Delivery Stage - reading BANNER" .

Comment: Do you have SMTP Relay setup on your org? The SMTP relay settings could be incorrect on this sandbox. Also, check the From address that is being used on the emails. If the from address is invalid, that may cause this issue.

Comment: Its resolved now, it was SMTP issue.